# OpenOffice SDK - Current opened document type

Tags: c++

Hello i'm looking for solution how to get **TYPE** of current opened document.

Example code :

```cpp
  Reference< XInterface  > Desktop = xServiceManager->createInstanceWithContext(
  OUString::createFromAscii("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop"), xContext);

  Reference< XDesktop > xDesktop(Desktop, UNO_QUERY);

  Reference< XComponent > xComponent = xDesktop->getCurrentComponent();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to get type of current opened document is:

```cpp
#include <com/sun/star/lang/XServiceInfo.hpp>
using namespace com::sun::star::lang;

/* ... */

Reference< XServiceInfo > xServiceInfo(xcomponent, UNO_QUERY);
OString documentType = OUStringToOString(xServiceInfo->getImplementationName(), RTL_TEXTENCODING_ASCII_US);

cout << documentType.pData->buffer;
```